# Checkbox to determine if an action is completed or not

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tkinter

I have a list of dictionaries of clients in a format like this:

```
dict_list = [{'Name of Business' : 'Amazon', 'Contact Name' : 'Jeff Bezos', 'Email' : 'Jeff@Amazon.com'}, {'Name of Business' : 'Microsoft', 'Contact Name' : 'Bill Gates', 'Email' : 'Bill@Microsoft.com'}]
```

and will be using `tkinter` to build rows for each client with a `checkbox` next to each. I will later add a `button` that, when pressed, will send an email to each client based on the information it pulls from the list.

Currently I am doing something like:

```
ClientCount = len(dict_list)
CurrentCount = 0 

while CurrentCount < ClientCount:
    for i in range(ClientCount):
        currentClient = Label(text='Client: ' + dict_list[i]['Client']).grid(row=[i], column=1)
        currentContactName = Label(text='Contact Name: ' + dict_list[i]['Contact Name']).grid(row=[i], column=2)
        currentEmail = Label(text='Contact Email: ' + dict_list[i]['Email']).grid(row=[i], column=3)
        CurrentCount += 1
```

First, I am sure there is an easier way to do this and will take any suggestions towards that but the main issue is adding a checkbox that will, when selected, determine whether or not to send an email to that client.
(A button, added later, will call a command that will check if each client is checked and only send to those that return true etc.)

I am not sure whether I should be creating a new variable to be checked, adding a key and a value to each dictionary to be read at a later point, etc.

Comment: I don't think there is any need for the `while` loop with the `CurrentCount += 1`...the for loop is enough...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should iterate directly over the list rather than using a counter and a while loop:

```
for client in dict_list:
    currentClient = Label(text='Client: ' + client['Client']).grid(row=[i], column=1)
    ...
```

Second, if you do `x=Label(...).grid(...)`, `x` will always be None. Best practice is to use two different statements. In this case the point is moot since you never use `currentClient`, but you should get in the habit of always separating them. Group your widget creation together, and your layout together, and your GUI will be much easier to manage:

```
for client in dict_list:
    clientLabel = Label(...)
    contactLabel = Label(...)
    emailLabel = Label(...)

    clientLabel.grid(...)
    contactLabel.grid(...)
    emailLabel.grid(...)
```

Third -- and this is the answer to your question -- you can create an instance of `IntVar` for each checkbutton, and store them either in a separate data structure or right along with your data. For example, to store them by business name you might do it like this:

```
cbVars = {}
for client in dict_list:
    ...
    bizname = client["Business Name"]
    cbVars[bizname] = IntVar()
    cb = Checkbutton(..., onvalue=1, offvalue = 0, variable = cbVars[bizname])
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help so far! The only problem Im having now is verifying that the variable is actually being modified by the checkbox. I made a command on the checkbox to return the variable but its always showing zero so I think Im still doing somethign wrong.