# Python Tkinter checkbox to modify an existing list dictionary value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tkinter

I have a list of dictionaries in a format like this:

```
dict_list = [{'Contact Name' : 'Jeff Bezos', 'Email' : 'Jeff@Amazon.com', 'Send' : 0},
 {'Contact Name' : 'Bill Gates', 'Email' : 'Bill@Microsoft.com', 'Send' : 0}]
```

I currently display each name using Tkinter:

```
for eachclient in dict_list:
   contactLabel = Label(text='Contact Name: ' + eachclient['Contact Name'])     
   emailLabel = Label(text='Contact Email: ' + eachclient['Email'])
```

I need a Tkinter checkbox that can modify the value of 'Send' for each entry in dict_list.
I will also add a send button that will send only if the checkbox is checked.
(The send button will call a command like:)

```
   def buttonCheck():
       for eachclient in dict_list:
           if eachclient 'Send' = 1:
              send the message
           else:
              skip this client
```

Is this possible? I greatly appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: What's your specific question? You have some code there. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Send is currently = 0. I need a Tkinter checkbox that, when checked, modifies the value to 1.

Comment: How is this question different than http://stackoverflow.com/q/34456661/7432?

Comment: Why can't you just do `dict_list[index]['Send'] = 1`?

Comment: Modifying an existing value in the dictionary is much different than creating a new dictionary and adding values to that. I do appreciate your previous help though Bryan Oakley.

Answer (score 0):

The checkboxes themselves could be part of the `for` loop, with this at the end:

```
checkbox = Button(text=str(check), command=checkemail, width=2)
# The str(check) part is for rows.
```

N.B. The buttons themselves will have to be in a grid, similar to this.

[image]

Using the `cget` method (see [this](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.cget-method) for an explanation, and see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6113152/5076688) for an example), the function for the checkbox could be like this:

```
def checkemail(): # Using an example function name
    x = int(checkbox.cget("text")) # Gets the row number (check)
    dict_list[x]['Send'] = 1 # Changes the value of 'Send' for the contact to 1
```

I hope this is helpful!